# Can some explain this InputMethod classes in OpenSudoku source code?

Tags: android

I am trying to understand the OpenSudoku source code. I understand how the Board is drawn and how the onTouch event is processed. The only problem is there is a whole InputMethod package and about 8 classes in the package. Why do we need that package in the first place? Also the InputMethod class has a initialize() function. Why is that? Can I disable touch or keyboard input specifically for my app?

Thanks for any help. I am still learning Android dev and this will be of help.

- P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [Creating Input Methods](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html) on the android developer site. I'm not familiar with OpenSudoku but I assume that they created an InputMethod that is only numbers or something so that you only input numbers into the TextViews in the grid.

[InputMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethod.html) doesn't have an initialize method so I think that is just a method they added to setup the InputMethod.